# How to drop all commits between two commits without interactive rebase

Tags: git

I have a branch `B` based off branch `master`, I want to rebase `B` onto branch `A` instead.

My problem is branch `A` is based off an earlier commit in `master` than `B`, so when I try and rebase `B` onto `A` it's bringing all the commit history of `master` since `A` was split from it.

Normally I would solve this problem with an interactive rebase and manually drop the unwanted commits, however in this case there are too many commits to handle in this way. What I want is a command that will allow me to drop all commits in branch `B` between it's last common ancestor with `A` and the tip of `master`.

IE. A command that drops commits 2-5 in the diagram below from branch `B`

```
* 099b4f7 (HEAD -> master) commit_6
| * a4b6a50 (B) some other commit
|/  
* 80cfbbc commit_5
* 49c40c9 commit_4
* 2923714 commit_3
* f78ee3c commit_2
| * f6d3601 (A) some commit
|/  
* df753e1 commit_1
```

Comment: Look at the first `--onto` example in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description - is it your case (except with different branch names, obviously)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is exactly the sort of situation the `--onto` option to `rebase` is for:

```
git switch B
git rebase --onto A master
```

This will write `B`'s commits onto `A` starting from the child of the latest common commit between `B` and `master`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# start from branch_B
git checkout branch_B

# back it up
git branch backup_B

# make it point to branch_A
git reset --hard branch_A

# bring all commits from branch_B not already on master
git cherry-pick master..backup_B
```

It will bring on `branch_A` every commit from `branch_B` that are **not reachable from `master`**, so it won't bring your commits 2, 3 and 4.